# Characterize interior and closure of a set by neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subseteq X$. Then the closure of $A$, denoted by $\overline A$, can be defined via neighborhood (nbh) as $$\overline A := \{x \in X \mid \forall \text{ nbh } V \text{ of } x, V\cap A \neq \varnothing\}.$$

We have $$\operatorname{int} A = \left ( \overline{A^c} \right)^c.$$

So $$\begin{align}
\operatorname{int} A &= \{x \in X \mid \forall \text{ nbh } V \text{ of } x, V\cap A^c \neq \varnothing\}^c \\
&= \{x \in X \mid \exists \text{ nbh } V \text{ of } x, V\cap A^c = \varnothing\} \\
&= \{x \in X \mid \exists \text{ nbh } V \text{ of } x, V\subseteq A\}.
\end{align}$$

---

Could you please verify if my understanding is correct?

Comment: I think these are correct, but it would be helpful to know what definition of interior and closure you're working with.  For example, I usually use the definition that the interior of $A$ is the union of all open sets contained within $A$, and the closure of $A$ is the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$.

Comment: @RobertShore my definitions of closure and interior are the same as yours :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct: the interior of $A$ can be seen as all $x$ such that a whole neighbourhood of $x$ sits inside $A$ (the points that are "well and truly inside $A$").

I don't see the charm (personally ) to derive this in such a formal matter, and I'd rather deduce the $\operatorname{int} A = \left ( \overline{A^c} \right)^c$ fact from such a definition instead of the other way round, as you seem to do. My personal educational history went like this:

In my first year (metric topology) I was taught the following pair of definitions for interior and closure: $\overline{A}$ is the set of $x$ whose every neighbourhood intersects $A$, i.e.

$$\overline{A}= \{x \in X\mid \forall V \in \mathcal{N}_x: V \cap A \neq \emptyset\}$$

and $$\operatorname{int} A = \{x \in X\mid \exists V \in \mathcal{N}_x: V \subseteq A\}$$

(I use $\mathcal N_x$ in both cases for the set of neighbourhoods of a points $x$; defined by open balls in my metric topology course). From this pair the mentioned duality $\operatorname{int} A = \left ( \overline{A^c} \right)^c$ follows easily (check this if you like). Moreover we defined a set to be open if it equals its interior and closed iff it equals its closure. The duality was then used to see that the complement of an open set is closed and vice versa...

A year later, in *general* topology, I was taught more general definitions (in a space $(X,\mathcal T)$, so we're given what the open and closed sets (the complements of open sets) are):

$$\overline{A}=\bigcap \{C\subseteq X\mid A \subseteq C; C \text{ closed }\}$$ i.e. the closure is the smallest closed set surrounding a set. Dually

$$\operatorname{int}(A)= \bigcup\{O \subseteq X\mid O \in \mathcal T; O \subseteq A\}$$

i.e. the largest open subset of $A$; the topology axioms ensure that both are well-defined.

You can then also show the duality easily and we proved the equivalence of these definitions with the first pair I gave (using open sets to define $\mathcal N_x$ in that course). So that have us two views to work with: a "point-based" one: closure and interior as nice points wrt $A$ and a "global" one, as maximally open and minimally closed sets.

It seems to me (reading many questions on this site) that most texts use some sort of weird mix of such definitions (or use limit points to define closure etc) instead of picking a consistent way of definition. Both are equivalent of course, but some proofs are easier (slightly) with one definition instead of the other, so it's good to be conversant with both IMO.

Hope this is useful to anyone.. (lockdown = too much time?)

Comment: Yess, it's better to be conversant with different equivalent definitions of the same concept.